# Is it possible to Stream data as input into MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

At the moment we could pass in folders/files as input for MapReduce job, but what I wanted to know if we could 'cat' data from HDFS (hdfs dfs -cat file.txt) and pass that as MapReduce job input?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it with Hadoop, but you can do it with Spark (spark can/does use hdfs).  Check out: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/streaming-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you could not do that with MapReduce.

Alternatives that can do that are: [SparkStreaming](https://spark.apache.org/streaming/) and [Storm](https://storm.apache.org).